# Foreign Key Inline Referencing Issue in SQL+

Tags: oracle10g, foreign-keys, constraints, sqlplus

When referencing a foreign key inline I get an error message when writing it this way:

`C_ID NUMBER(6)
CONSTRAINT ORDERS_C_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (C_ID) REFERENCES customer(C_ID),`

The Error being: ERROR at line 7: ORA-02253: constraint specification not allowed here

But yet it works this way (which it should):

`C_ID NUMBER(6),
CONSTRAINT ORDERS_C_ID_fk FOREIGN KEY (C_ID) REFERENCES customer(C_ID),`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline reference constraints do not need `FOREIGN KEY (C_ID)`.  Use this instead:

```
C_ID NUMBER(6) CONSTRAINT ORDERS_C_ID_fk REFERENCES customer(C_ID)
```